# Query in rails with where array clause

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, where-clause

I have an array field, author_ids in books table, I need to write a query to find the array data.

Is there any way i can get, even if `author_ids has [1,3]` in its value, but when I check with `array [1,5]`, I still could get the data because it has 1 common ? here('author_ids @> ARRAY[?]::integer[]',[1,5])

```
where('author_ids @> ARRAY[?]::integer[]',[1,5])
```

this doesnot return data, `where('author_ids @> ARRAY[?]::integer[]',[1,3])` whis does because It has [1,3]. Iwant to get the data `where [auther_ids] ? any [passed_aray]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

[Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)

**Problem**

> anyarray @> anyarray → boolean
>
> Does **the first array contain the second**, that is, does each element
> appearing in the second array equal some element of the first array?
> (Duplicates are not treated specially, thus ARRAY[2] and ARRAY[1,1]
> are each considered to contain the other.)
>
> ARRAY[1,4,3] @> ARRAY[3,1,3] → t

That means if you have [1,3,7,9] for authors_ids and you query that with [1, 5] it's not going to return anything. Why?

@> checks if your query array is a subset of the column and [1,5] isn't a subset of [1,3,7,9] cause 5 is missing.

**Solution**

The operator you need is `&&`:

> anyarray && anyarray → boolean
>
> Do the arrays overlap, that is, have any elements in common?
>
> ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1] → t

Using that your query would be the following:

```
where('author_ids && ARRAY[?]::integer[]',[1,5])
```

**Refactor**

I think the correct would be to use a has_many association on your model for the Author class.

```
class CurrentModel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :authors
end
```

And then your query would be the following:

```
joins(:authors).where(authors: { id: [1,5] }
```

Comment: yes, but I cannt change the model right now, so I need to check with the array field. ANy method to work with this?

Comment: @NabinaKhadka Yes, it is the first thing I posted `where("author_ids && ?", "{1, 5}")`

Comment: Ths query doesnot work for array ?, I actually have plucked the id that I am going to chec, `where("author_ids && ?", "book_ids")`, `book_ids = [1,2,3]` I will be getting book_ids in array

Comment: @NabinaKhadka I updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: Perfect explanation, Thank you veryy veryy much